# SQLite exclude while still included in LIMIT clause

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

What I would like to do is have the excluded results still count towards the LIMIT clause. Using the below any excluded results do not count towards the 7 returned results. How can I accomplish something like this?

```
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM DBNAME DATAS WHERE A01 <> '' ORDER BY DATETIME(A01Date) DESC LIMIT 7) TMP ORDER BY DATETIME(A01Date) ASC"
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.
>   — David Wheeler

To apply the LIMIT before the WHERE, move it into a separate subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM DBName
            ORDER BY datetime(A01Date) DESC
            LIMIT 7)
      WHERE A01 <> '')
ORDER BY datetime(A01Date) ASC;
```

And now you can merge the two outermost queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM DBName
      ORDER BY datetime(A01Date) DESC
      LIMIT 7)
WHERE A01 <> ''
ORDER BY datetime(A01Date) ASC;
```